# помогите исправить данный код!

Tags: python

задание: Напишите функцию first, которая будет принимать вообще все что угодно и возвращать свой первый аргумент. Если все её аргументы именованные, то пускай она возвращает тот у которого самое маленькое имя. Если ей не передано ничего, то пускай она возвращает None.

```
first(0.0123) == 0.0123
first(1, 0.0123, 0) == 1
first(a = "Hi!") == "Hi!"
first(1, 2, 3, ["a"], b = "honey") == 1
first() is None
```

наш код:

```
def first(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return min(len(kwargs)) 
    elif len(args) == 0 and len(kwargs)==0:
        return None 
    elif len(args) and len(kwargs):
        newlist = [args, kwargs]
        return newlist[0]
```

Comment: return min(len(kwargs))  тут вы возвращаете длину, а не аргумент. А если и такие, и такие заданы, то наверное, надо возвращать args[0] - неименованные сначала идут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
def first(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        return args[0]
    elif kwargs:
        return kwargs[min(kwargs, key=len)]


def main():
    result = first()
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Тесты:***

```py
print(first(1, 2, 3))                               # 1
print(first(abc='Hello!', de='World!', f='Spam!'))  # Spam!
print(first(1, 2, 3, f='Spam!'))                    # 1
print(first())                                      # None
```

Comment: мы тебя любим ☼

Comment: @iwannabeadog Я вас тоже <3